# Failed to read key hailun_logistics from store "/Users/yangshin/Documents/hailun_logisticskey.jks"

Tags: android

I'm trying to generate signed `APK`, but I'm getting this error message.

Log:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':haiLunLogisticsAndroid:packageRelease'.
```

> Failed to read key hailun_logistics from store "/Users/yangshin/Documents/hailun_logisticskey.jks": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Could somebody point me to why it failed?

Answer (score 0):

*Normal Password Errors...*?

- Key Store file located where permission to access is denied to IDE. (Run IDE as admin)
- Mismatch Letters
- Caps Lock

If all this fails, create a new *.jks* keystore file and set **keystore password** and **alias password to be same**. Simpler to remember.